# Why the shuffled number sequence on programming dvorak?

Tags: keyboard-layout, dvorak

To my surprise I couldn't find this question already answered anywhere, so here I am asking, hoping that understanding the idea behind it would help me learn their positions faster.

So, why are the positions of the numbers on the programming dvorak how they are?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The most used numbers are in the easiest locations for your fingers while they are on the home row. :)
Also odd on the left and even on the right.

Also, read http://programmer-dvorak.appspot.com/

Comment: Probably because left-right alternation is a Dvorak thing ... you can see this in Korean keyboards though, although I'm not sure if their numbers are alternated as well.

Comment: @Jack Why is zero not in continuation of the sequence, but breaks the sequence by being placed in the middle instead of at the left end?

Comment: Either because 0 and 9 are types the most (reached by index finger) or because they tried to be fancy :)

Answer (score 2):

The Programmer Dvorak Keyboard Layout simply kept the original number sequence: https://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/

> Note that the numbers are placed in an odd-even sequence, as in the original Dvorak layout.

Regarding the odd-even sequence, the smallest numerals are the most (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law) frequently used, they are therefore moved to the dominant fingers.